# Automate source formatting for specific folders in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

In Eclipse you can format the whole source tree. You can format the whole project by right clicking it -> Source -> Format. You can do the same for sub-folders. I want to be able to do this automated for a specific set of sub-folders in my project, is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the formatter run [automatically on saving files](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-save-actions.htm), but the formatting is only applied to the edited files then (not a specific folder).

However, I do not see any good reason to not format all sources of a project the same way, which is why I hope you can take that as solution. :)

Comment: I use PDT to write PHP, not Java. PDT doesn't support this functionality, so thanks for your answer, but it isn't sufficient.

Comment: That's what "tags" on stackoverflow are good for. In Eclipse, functionality related to the editors of a certain language is almost always specific to that single language, so you should mention it beforehand. :)